# Find 3g Frequency and Channel Number in mobile network programmatically in Android?

Tags: android, network-programming

Developed code for signal strength. Now am trying to find out frequency and channel number.

```
public class myPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
    int SignalStrengthOfTower  = 0;
    int EcNo=0;
    public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength) {
       super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength);
       SignalStrengthOfTower = signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength();
       SignalStrengthOfTower = (2 * SignalStrengthOfTower) - 113;
       signalStrengthNetwork=String.valueOf(SignalStrengthOfTower);
       signalview.setText(signalStrengthNetwork);
     }
}
```

Comment: did you get frequency or bank number?